# Telegram bot clickable commands in groups but clicking on them mentions the bot

Tags: node.js, telegram, telegram-bot

I have a Telegram bot (in Node JS).

I sent a list of the commands to BotFather:

```
command 1 - description 1
command 2 - description 2
```

**It works well in private**. When I type "/" I see the list of commands available and when I click on one it sends the message "command 1" on the chat.

But when I do this **in a group**, although it displays the commands too, when I click it sends this message "**command 1@botusername**", so it doesn't work.

Why is this happening? I'd like the same behavior on groups.

Comment: do you mind sharing the code where you implemented this in Nodejs?

Comment: @RotimiBest Actually there is no code needed to put commands in place. It's done from talking to Bot Father in private on Telegram.

Comment: Have you found any solution? Though for now I'm using `/cmd || /cmd@usernameBot` so it will recognize both/

Comment: @Dharmaraj No I didn't, I'm doing something similar to you.

Comment: @MarieDm what's your solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is because you're using the wrong casing system.

/command 1@botusername is not a proper command casing.

When you insert a space between the command name telegram assumes the command has ended at `/command` and then assumes the rest `1@botusername` as either a command payload or just a text so it tags the bot since it's a username.

Anyways you should avoid adding space between a command I recommend using either snake casing or just write them without spaces also known us no casing like this

```
nocasecommand - description 1 or 
snake_case_command - description 1
```

I have tried other casings like camelCase or PacsalCase though it works if you write the command down in a group or private. You can't add it to the preset command options because telegram doesn't support uppercase letters in their command options, I guess. [For more Check out this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Ip6h.png).